# Conversion from type 'Range' to type 'String' is not valid.in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel-2007

When clicking 'Download Catalogue' button while debugging this error occurs "Conversion from type 'Range' to type 'String' is not valid".An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.

```
        If Trim(.Cells._Default(1, 1)) = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Enter the Auction No in Cell B2 ", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Exit Function
        Else

            StrAuctionNo = Trim(.Cells._Default(1, 1))
        End If
```

Comment: I don't think you should use the "_Default()" function. I'd say it's for internal usage. How about "cellRange.cells(1, 1).Value"?

Comment: If Trim(.Cells._cellRange.cells(1, 1).Value) = ""           I used like this.Then again error occurs .An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMember Exception' occured.Additional inf: Public member '_cellRange' on type 'Range' not found.

Comment: the "cellRange" is what you already have before the "." Unfortunately your code is not showing how you get the Range. Just use ".Cells(1, 1).Value" instead of ".Cells._Default(1,1)"

Comment: I convert all default functions to this. If Trim(.Cells(1, 1).Value) = "" .But again I got this error "Conversion from type 'Range' to type 'String' is not valid".

Comment: But in the code below are present....                             Private WithEvents exApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Private exBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Private ExSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is the Vb.net version:

```
Public Sub Test()
    dim excel as new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim cellRange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
    Dim sheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\Book1.xls")

    sheet = workbook.Sheets(1)
    cellRange = sheet.Range("A1:B2")
    Dim val As String = cellRange.Cells(2,2).Value

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(val) orelse val.Trim() = String.Empty Then
        MsgBox("Field missing ....")
    Else 
        MsgBox("OK!!")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot use Dim r as range in Microsoft Visual Basic 2008

Comment: Because Type range is not defined and need to import excel.

Comment: Import types or leave it object. Vb.net should be fine with that.

Comment: But my code have...... Private WithEvents exApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Private exBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Private ExSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

Comment: I have changed my answer.

Comment: Again error....MissingMemberException was caught.Public member 'cellRange' on type 'Worksheet' not found.

Comment: Sorry, don't know what you are doing. Why you try to call "cellRange" on "Worksheet". Maybe you should update your code to show waht you have.

Comment: Make a small example containing only this use-case. Get rid of other functions (if any) not related to the problem. But then show everything, Imports, constructors etc. . And don't worry about errors. If there aren't errors, you wouldn't be here ;-)